# How do I print to a text field in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to code a button to print a single char '^' to the textfield labeled propA. Does anyone know of a method that will do this or how to create one?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var propA: [UITextField]!

    @IBAction func orButton(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        print("or") //test
        //print to text field propA
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for propA.text = "^"

Comment: You're having a problem with your IBOutlet, It's an array of UITextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your `@IBOutlet` like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var propA: UITextField!
```

To set the text to the text field, use this:

```
@IBAction func orButton(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    propA.text = "or"
}
```

Comment: @MeccaMiles No problem. Glad I could help :)